# Access to excel file in the server without installing excel

Tags: excel, interop, ms-office, com+, dcom

I've created a library to pass/get data to/from excel.

To execute in my machine i modified the access permisions in COM+ console.

The thing is that im interested in upload this component to my online server, but there i havent installed excel.

Are there any way to register excel in COM+ without install excel?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards.

Jose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your library uses Office Interops to manipulate Excel, then no you can't register Excel in COM+ without installing Excel, since there would be nothing to register against, or interop for that matter.

Even if you use late binding in your code, so that it compiles, you will experience runtime errors if the Excel components are not installed.

"*All current versions of Microsoft Office were designed, tested, and configured to run as end-user products on a client workstation. They assume an interactive desktop and user profile. They do not provide the level of reentrancy or security that is necessary to meet the needs of server-side components that are designed to run unattended.*" - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: Yes, use the interop library.

Thanks for this clear response.

Best Regards.